# AJAX прогрузка в DLE

Tags: dle

Недавно решил сделать AJAX подгрузку, но при нажатии кнопки "Показать ещё" кнопка не исчезает, взамен этого подгружается необходимый контент с дубликацией этой же кнопки.

Как решить вопрос дубликации?

```
<a onclick="nextPage(); return false;" style="cursor: pointer">Показать еще</a>

<div class="nav-load" id="ajax-next-page" style="display: none;">[next-link][/next-link]</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function nextPage() {
    var nextPage = $('#ajax-next-page a').attr('href');
    ShowLoading("");
    if (nextPage !== undefined) {
     $.ajax({
       url: nextPage,
       success: function(data) {
         $('#ajax-next-page').remove();
         $('#next-page').remove();
         HideLoading("");
         $('#dle-content').append($('#dle-content', data).html());
       }
     })
   }
 };
</script>
```

Comment: Тогда, пожалуйста, скиньте свой вариант изменённого кода. Или, как вы предлагаете изменить данный код?

Comment: Ну так хотя бы: `var url = $('#ajax-next-page a').attr('href');`. Что же касается самого вопроса, то возможно так: `$(event.target).is('a') && $(event.target).remove();` перед отправкой AJAX запроса.

Comment: Спасибо, при использовании первого метода меняется URL (от чего мы избавлялись), а вторая строчка решила проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Для этой цели лучше использовать плагин [Infinite Scroll Reimagined](https://infiniteajaxscroll.com/)

В navigation.tpl вашего шаблона указать:

```
<div id="page_navigation" class="page_navigation">[next-link]Дальше[/next-link]</div>
```

Подключите в main.tpl вашего шаблона файл плагина:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{THEME}/js/jquery.ias.min.js"></script>
```

В js файл вашего шаблона добавить:

```
var ias = $.ias({
        container : '#dle-content',
        item: '.item',
        pagination: '#page_navigation',
        next: '.page_navigation a',
        delay: 10
});
ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());
ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({html: '<div class="ias-noneleft" style="">Новостей больше нет</div>'}));
```

Comment: Такой код сейчас и стоит. Он работает как AJAX прогрузка, но при этом меняется URL

Comment: Парсер с граббером обошёлся дешевле, чем стоимость этого плагина, при том что в нём всего одна возможность) Цена не оправдана)

Comment: Да, цена 15$, вы считаете оно того стоит?

Comment: Мы разбираемся во всём, кроме JS, нам нужна загрузка по кнопке, не все устройства поддерживают автоматическую подгрузку, к тому же это дополнительная нагрузка, ибо не всем необходимо прогружать страницу.